# How to make java wait for an event?

Tags: java, events

Im writing a simple tictactoe game where each player can either be human or AI.
So to create a new instance of game, i made it such that all I do is:

```
Player p1=new RLPlayer(world);
gameInstance = new GameInstance(this, p1, new HumanPlayer(this, world), world);
```

However, if I do something like

```
Player p1=new RLPlayer(world);
gameInstance = new GameInstance(this, p1, new HumanPlayer(this, world), world);
Player p2=new RLPlayer(world);
gameInstance = new GameInstance(this, p2, new HumanPlayer(this, world), world);
```

Only 1 game gets played. I've figured out this is due to the fact that for the HumanPlayer, it stops and does nothing while waiting for the move input and if theres code after that, it just skips on to that. How do I make the execution wait for the input? Or is my approach totally wrong? I have a feeling it is.

```
public class HumanPlayer implements Player {
    private GameGUI gameGUI;
    private TicTacToeWorld world;

    public HumanPlayer(GameGUI gameGUI, TicTacToeWorld world){
        this.gameGUI = gameGUI;
        this.world = world;
    }

    public boolean makeMove() {
        gameGUI.setMoveInputEnabled(true);
        return false;
    }

    public boolean makeMove(int move){ //false means no move made
        if(!world.isMoveLegal(move)) return false;

        world.makeMove(move);
        gameGUI.setMoveInputEnabled(false);
        return true;
    }

    public void observeMove(){
    }

}
```

Just for some context. I think the problem is in the one above.

```
public class GameInstance {
    private Player[] players;
    private TicTacToeWorld world;
    private GameGUI gameGUI;


    public GameInstance(GameGUI gameGUI, Player player1, Player player2, TicTacToeWorld world){
        this.gameGUI = gameGUI;
        players = new Player[]{player1,player2};
        this.world = world;

        runGame();
    }

    public void runGame(){
        gameGUI.updateGUI(world.getWorldState());
        while(!world.isGameOver()){
            if(!makePlayerMove())return;
            gameGUI.updateGUI(world.getWorldState());
        }
    }

    public boolean makePlayerMove(){
        int[] state;
        state = world.getWorldState();

        if(players[(state[0]-1)%2].makeMove()){
            players[state[0]%2].observeMove();
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }

    public void makePlayerMove(int move){ //force move AI OR input human move
        int[] state;
        state = world.getWorldState();

        if( players[(state[0]-1)%2].makeMove(move) ){ //if move was made e.g. AI. Human player would return false;
            gameGUI.updateGUI(world.getWorldState());
            players[state[0]%2].observeMove();
            runGame();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Research Observer pattern...

Comment: State pattern may be better here.

Comment: i googled those patterns but i dont get how they remove the need to make the program wait. could you give a brief explanation?

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully you figured this out a while ago, but just for completeness:

Your game has to run off events on the GUI.  Specifically, your AI move code has to be run in response to the click where the human player makes his move--in the implementation of the ActionLister's actionPerformed method.  You need to think in terms of the GUI--buttons and things--*not* in terms of game flow.  Or rather, you've got recreate proper game flow building on GUI events.